# Is there a way to edit NFT metadata in python?

Tags: nft, metadata, python, nfts, solana.py

I've been using solana-py in python to interact with Solana for a bit now. And I've been wondering if there's a way to update NFT metadata in python. I'd assume you can't do it on solana-py. So I was wondering if there were other libraries I could use to update metadata in python. If there's no way to do it in python I plan on learning rust so I could use that. But it would be much easier to do it in python. If anyone knows how to update NFT metadata please share. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 2):

You can try to rewrite Metaplex sdk in python (a lot of people would be grateful)

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js

What you're looking for is in

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js/blob/main/packages/js/src/plugins/nftModule/updateNft.ts

Here's an example of reading Metaplex data that I wrote:

https://github.com/vicyyn/MetaplexMetadata-js

Updating the NFT is updating the pda to new data that you send.
Follow this structure.

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#the-nft-model

IN order to update the pda you have to call Metaplex Token Program and call updateMetadataAccountV2

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/processor.rs#L322

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used 2 projects to update NFT metadata:

1. Metaboss: https://github.com/samuelvanderwaal/metaboss
2. arloader: https://github.com/CalebEverett/arloader

But they are both written in rust. So do not know if it will be helpful for you.